# Magic Square Challenge

Tags: code-golf

For the purpose of this question, a magic square is an `n`×`n` square of (not necessarily distinct) positive integers, where all rows, columns, and main diagonals add to a "magic constant" `m`.

#### Your Task

Create a function or full program that, given the magic number `m` and a list representing a square **with at most one wrong number in each row and column**, will output a list with the entries rearranged to represent a correct square. Your program will be expected to handle any solvable square of any size. Your program should take less than twenty minutes for n=7 or smaller. Assume that all input is solvable.

#### Example Input (list, m)

```
[16, 16, 11, 9, 14, 17, 9, 29, 13, 1, 15, 5, 6, 16, 15, 7, 3, 17, 11, 12, 14, 17, 3, 8, 6], 58
```

which represents this square<sup>1</sup>:

> 16 16 **11** 09 14
>    **17** 09 29 13 01
>    15 05 06 **16** 15
>    07 **03** 17 11 12
>    14 17 03 08 **06**

A compliant solution has to solve the following 7x7 square within the time limit.

```
[31, 19, 10, 13, 14, 32, 15, 6, 21, 17, 22, 30, 17, 7, 17, 30, 17, 24, 17, 11, 8, 7, 22, 33, 13, 15, 17, 11, 14, 16, 21, 22, 13, 11, 29, 16, 13, 3, 19, 12, 12, 43, 27, 13, 19, 13, 20, 18, 11], 123
```

#### Example Output

For the first test case, this is the only correct solution.

```
[16, 16, 3, 9, 14, 6, 9, 29, 13, 1, 15, 5, 6, 17, 15, 7, 11, 17, 11, 12, 14, 17, 3, 8, 16]
```

For a bonus of **-10**, format your output into a square and pad single digits with zeroes as below.<sup>2</sup>

> 16 16 **03** 09 14
>    **06** 09 29 13 01
>    15 05 06 **17** 15
>    07 **11** 17 11 12
>    14 17 03 08 **16**

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Bolded numbers are in incorrect cells.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>Bolded numbers have switched cells.</sub>

Comment: There is no well-defined answer. I might as well always print out the same solved magic square, because I can argue that I corrected the input to it.

Comment: @orlp I updated my question to be more specific. Now it states that you can't change any of the numbers in the original list, only move them around, and not add any new ones.

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be solveable? What should we do if it isn't?

Comment: Do we have to handle any dimensions or will it always be 5x5?

Comment: The golfiest approach I can think of is going to be sheer brute force on permutations. Is there a time constraint, or is this okay?

Comment: The value of `n` is redundant, right? It could easily be derived from the values. And I was just about to ask the same thing as @Geobits. If you don't constrain the runtime, you'll see solutions that theoretically solve this, but not before the sun burns out.

Comment: @RetoKoradi You can derive `n` by summing everything up and and dividing by the width/height of the square but I feel like it would be easier to take it as input. Also the rules say it's supposed to be taken as input

Comment: @Geobits I updated my question to have a time constraint since brute force permutations are boring and I'd like to see some better answers than that

Comment: @PeterTaylor I also said the time constraint only applies up to squares of size 7x7.

Comment: @PeterTaylor No I will not change it. I'm just putting a time constraint on it so people won't try all permutations of the square. That would be 49^49 permutations for a 7x7 square and I know for a fact that it doesn't run in less than 20 minutes. Even 5x5 squares wont meet the time constraint. If someone shows me an 8x8 or larger square then the time constraint won't matter for that square but if the same program for a 7x7 squares takes longer than 20 minutes then it is not a valid solution

Comment: Not that it matters, but there are at most `49!` distinct permutations of a 7x7 square.

Comment: @Dennis 49! = 608281864034267560872252163321295376887552831379210240000000000. 49^49 = 66009724686219550843768321818371771650147004059278069406814190436565131829325062449.

Comment: just a slightly unreasonable number of recursive steps

Comment: Have you written a valid solution yourself? I'm not convinced this is even possible.

Comment: I've written a simple one but I know the logic behind a more complex one but I just can't figure out how to write it in code for the life of me. I have the grid simplified down to a point where permutations are a viable option but I have two separate lists that need to be compared while finding each new list of permutations and I can't figure out how to do that part.

Comment: I do have a solver that can handle one mismatched number in each row/column but not for multiple. I'm thinking about updating the problem to only handle the cases of one in each row/column since I can't figure out the multiple myself. Let me know what you think about that

Comment: @SirParselot Yes, I think you it would be good to restrict it to a single mismatch.

Comment: @xnor I did update so it is now a single mismatch although I left the multiple mismatch up if someone wants an extra challenge for some reason.

Comment: @SirParselot The update is easy to miss in the example input section. You should explain it clearly under "Your task", perhaps with an example to illustrate what a single mismatch is.

Comment: @SirParselot I removed the multiple-mismatch test cases, because that kind of broke "objective winning criterion"; please roll back any edits you disagree with.

Comment: What does "*at most one wrong number in each row and column*" mean? Is it that there exists a solution which changes at most one *cell* in each row and column, or is it that there exists a solution in which each solved row differs from the corresponding input row in at most a replacement of one entry and a permutation, and likewise for columns?

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>73</s> 70 bytes

```
q~:Q,mQ:Le!{QL/.{1$W$W*t_:+W*t}:Te_$Q$=Tz{W%_L,.=a\}2*++::+)-!*}=&T"%02d "ffe%N*
```

The above code is 80 bytes long and qualifies for the bonus.

Time complexity is **O(n!)** for **n×n** squares. For **9×9**, this translates to 7 seconds on my machine.

Try it online: [permalink for Chrome](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3AQ%2CmQ%3ALe!%7BQL%2F.%7B1%24W%24W*t_%3A%2BW*t%7D%3ATe_%24Q%24%3DTz%7BW%25_L%2C.%3Da%5C%7D2*%2B%2B%3A%3A%2B)-!*%7D%3D%26T%22%2502d%20%22ffe%25N*&input=123%20%5B31%2019%2010%2013%2014%2032%2015%206%2021%2017%2022%2030%2017%207%2017%2030%2017%2024%2017%2011%208%207%2022%2033%2013%2015%2017%2011%2014%2016%2021%2022%2013%2011%2029%2016%2013%203%2019%2012%2012%2043%2027%2013%2019%2013%2020%2018%2011%5D) | [permalink for Firefox](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3AQ%2CmQ%3ALe!%7BQL%2F.%7B1%24W%24W*t_%3A%2BW*t%7D%3ATe_%24Q%24%3DTz%7BW%2525_L%2C.%3Da%5C%7D2*%2B%2B%3A%3A%2B)-!*%7D%3D%26T%22%252502d%20%22ffe%2525N*&input=123%20%5B31%2019%2010%2013%2014%2032%2015%206%2021%2017%2022%2030%2017%207%2017%2030%2017%2024%2017%2011%208%207%2022%2033%2013%2015%2017%2011%2014%2016%2021%2022%2013%2011%2029%2016%2013%203%2019%2012%2012%2043%2027%2013%2019%2013%2020%2018%2011%5D)

Comment: Nice work, +1. As a complete aside, the permalink for Chrome works in Safari but the Firefox one does not.